# how to specify login role(user) in postgresql

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, authentication, roles

I am trying to learn SQL. I have picked up postresql . now I hae a query myself. How can specify login role(user) or switch the role ?

I had create new users like this:-

in zsh shell with postgres user

```
% createuser --interactive sqltest01
```

and

```
% psql
postgres=> create user sqltest02 with password '1';
CREATE ROLE
```

now I have 3 users or roles

```
postgres=> \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 sqltest01 | Create role, Create DB                                     | {}
 sqltest02 |                                                            | {}
```

How can I login with these users ?

I usely login like this :-

% sudo su postgres
% psql

which logs me in with user postgres

```
 \conninfo 
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

how can I login with sqltest01 or sqltest02 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logged into the same computer that Postgres is running on you can use the following psql login command, specifying the database (mydb) and username (myuser):

```
psql -d mydb -U myuser
```

If for some reason you are not prompted for a password when issuing these commands, you can use the -W option:

```
psql -d mydb -U myuser -W
```